# Notwendigkeit von "auf" in "sich etwas auf etwas zugutehalten"

Tags: usage

Aus dem *Spiegel-Magazin*:

> Er studierte Betriebswirtschaftslehre und gründete mit anderen ein Start-up-Unternehmen, sie entwickelten eine App, die dabei hilft, Prüfungen vorzubereiten. 18 Mitarbeiter hat dieses Unternehmen. Weisser ist schon wieder ausgestiegen, um weiter zu studieren. Ein BWL-Bürschchen ist er nicht. Er ist ein junger Mann mit Lebenserfahrung, **ohne dass er sich das zugutehält**. Sein Auftritt ist bescheiden.

Im [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/zugutehalten) lautet die Verwendung von **zugutehalten**:

> sich  etwas auf etwas zugutehalten (gehoben: auf etwas stolz sein; sich etwas auf etwas einbilden: sie hält sich etwas auf ihre gute Bildung zugute)

Sollte der Satz nicht eher wie Folgendes lauten:

> Er ist ein junger Mann mit Lebenserfahrung, **ohne dass er sich etwas darauf zugutehält**.

? Gilt der Ausgangssatz vom Spiegel als richtig oder nicht?

Comment: Hm... Spontan die Variante vom Spiegel, wobei mir nicht ganz klar ist, was die aussagen wollen. Ich kenne "jemandem etwas zugutehalten" im Sinne von "nachsichtig sein". Das passt hier aber im Kontext nicht. Laut Duden gibt es noch "sich etwas auf etwas zugutehalten", im Sinne von "stolz sein". Das passt aber im Kontext nicht genau so wenig. "Stolz sein" und "bescheidener Auftritt" passen nicht.

Comment: Der Spiegel Autor hat ein seltenes Verb gebraucht und es ging schief. Er wollte schreiben »… ohne daß er sich was darauf einbildet«, und das hätte jeder verstanden. Du hast recht, wenn schon »zugutehalten«, dann gemäß deiner korrigierten Version (mit »darauf«). Aber »einbilden« paßt besser und wird leichter verstanden.

Comment: @Lumi Das macht Sinn. Vielleicht kannst Du das eine Antwort machen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wenn man es ganz genau nimmt, steht in diesem [Duden-Eintrag](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/zugutehalten):

> **Wendungen, Redensarten, Sprichwörter**
>
> - jemandem etwas zugutehalten (gehoben: etwas zu jemandes Entschuldigung berücksichtigen: man muss ihm seine Unerfahrenheit zugutehalten)
> - sich `<Dativ>` etwas auf etwas zugutehalten (gehoben: auf etwas stolz sein; sich etwas auf etwas einbilden: sie hält sich etwas auf ihre gute Bildung zugute)

Du siehst, es gibt also zwei verschiedene Verwendungen für das Verb `zugutehalten`. In deinem Textbeispiel

> Er ist ein junger Mann mit Lebenserfahrung, ohne dass er sich das zugutehält. Sein Auftritt ist bescheiden.

wird `zugutehalten` richtig verwendet und es handelt es sich ganz klar um Fall 1: etwas zu jemandes Entschuldigung berücksichtigen. Der junge Mann könnte sein junges Alter mit dem Umstand, dass er schon Lebenserfahrung besitzt, entschuldigen, tut es aber nicht.

Dein Vorschlag

> Er ist ein junger Mann mit Lebenserfahrung, ohne dass er sich etwas darauf zugutehält.

wäre gemäss Duden auch korrekt, aber meine *subjektive* Wahrnehmung ist, dass es eine sehr seltene Konstruktion ist - und das "gehoben" deutet ebenfalls darauf hin.

Comment: Ich finde nicht, dass Bedeutung 1 im Kontext passt. "Sein Auftritt ist bescheiden" kann in zweierlei Hinsicht gedeutet werden. Wenn der Auftritt 'mäßig' ist, so müsste ihm sein junges Alter zugutegehalten werden, und außerdem hieße es mit Sicherheit, er hätte eben noch keine Lebenserfahrung aufgrund seines jungen Alters. Ist sein Auftritt 'zurückhaltend', so macht "ohne dass er sich das zugutehält" vollkommen fehl am Platz. Immerhin ist ein 'zurückhaltender, bescheidener Auftritt' nichts was negative Kritik verdiene. – Die 2.te Duden-Bedeutung macht übrigens genauso wenig Sinn.

Comment: Deiner Interpretation "Der junge Mann könnte sein junges Alter mit dem Umstand, dass er schon Lebenserfahrung besitzt, entschuldigen, tut es aber nicht" kann ich nicht zustimmen. Im Ausgangssatz ist es nicht klar, dass er nur sein Alter (und nicht sein Alter und seine Lebenserfahrung) entschuldigen würde.